# Identify the proper checkbox and button

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have the followings;

```
<div class="trp">
    <input class="makeActive" type="checkbox">
    <input class="makeRepeat" type="checkbox">

    <button class="btn" data-item="makeActive">Make Active</button>
    <button class="btn" data-item="makeRepeat" checked="checked">Make Active</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do,

1. If I click any of the button, The checkbox which having the class
   name equal to the clicked button's data-item should be checked and
   needs to add a class name called .active to the button.
2. If any of the checkbox is already checked when the page loads, Needs to identify 
   the button related to that checkbox and needs to add the
   class .active.

I managed to check the checkbox when button is clicked using this

```
$('.trp .btn').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).attr('data-item');
    var cb = $(this).closest('.trp').find('.'+elem);


    if (cb.is(':checked')) {
        cb.prop('checked',false);
    } else {
        cb.prop('checked',true);
    }           
});
```

But I couldnt do the 2nd point as I mentioned above.

Can you please help me do this...

Regards, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.trp input[type=checkbox][checked=checked]').each(function (index, element) {
        var button = $('.trp button:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uSBS/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried this and this adding the active class to the first button not for the actual button

Comment: @user1915190 It works perfectly fine, adding jsfiddle to my example.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger your click event handler after binding it:

```
$('.trp .btn').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).attr('data-item');
    var cb = $(this).closest('.trp').find('.'+elem);


    if (cb.is(':checked')) {
        cb.prop('checked',false);
    } else {
        cb.prop('checked',true);
    }           
})
// Trigger click
.click();
```

Or put your event handler in a function an call it on pageload.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.trp input:checkbox').each(function () {
    var this = $(this);
    if (this.is(':checked')) {
        $('.trp input:button').filter(function () {
            return ($(this).data('item') === this.attr('class'))
        }).addClass('.active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').is(':checked').each(function(){
        var elem = $(this).attr('data-item');
        $('.'+elem).addClass('active')
    })
})
```